# How do I assign values to variables that are returned by an If statement

Tags: python, list

I am writing a program that returns indices of an element in a list that is duplicated. I first check whether the index of every element in the list is greater than 1 then I store that index in c. After that, I perform a for loop that checks if any index in the range of the length of my list matches that of c(the index of the element that occurs more than once). The issue is since I get more than one index, in this case, 2 and 3, I don't know how to store them in variables.

```
s = 'hello'
s = [x for x in s]
for i in s1:
    if s.index(i) > 1:
        c = s1.index(i)
for index in range(len(s)):
    if s[index] == c:
        c1, c2 = index, index  #this is my attempt to store the indeces in variables c1 and c2 but when i try to print them out i get a NameError: 'c1' not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you have an arbitrary unknown number of values, you want to put them in a list rather than into their own named variables:

```
c_indices = []
for index in range(len(s)):
    if s[index] == c:
        c_matches.append(index)
```

or, as a comprehension:

```
c_indices = [index for index, char in enumerate(s) if c == char]
```